# Presto - Insert Missing Timestamps

Tags: sql, presto

EDIT: Made a few clarifications in the post below

I am trying to work on a problem where I have a table that has missing timestamps. Let's say there is a table like this:

| Timestamp | NumericField |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-24 16:59:00.000 | 101 |
| 2021-10-24 16:57:00.000 | 101 |

I would like to try and do 2 things:

1. Populate a third record where the timestamp would be 2021-10-24 16:58:00.000.
2. Along with that, I would like to populate the NumericField field as 101 if the lead and lag records match, like in this example. The result would be:

| Timestamp | NumericField |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-24 16:59:00.000 | 101 |
| 2021-10-24 16:58:00.000 | 101 |
| 2021-10-24 16:57:00.000 | 101 |

If the lead and lag NumericField records do not match, then the NumericField that was generated would result in null. Example being:

| Timestamp | NumericField |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-24 16:59:00.000 | 101 |
| 2021-10-24 16:58:00.000 | NULL |
| 2021-10-24 16:57:00.000 | 100 |

The reason I am posting this question is because recursive CTE's isn't supported in Presto and I couldn't find any good resources to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using `lag` to find previous values and then `sequence` to generate array of dates with `interval '1' minute` step, unnest it and union the result with original table:

```sql
WITH dataset (Timestamp, NumericField) AS (
    VALUES (timestamp '2021-10-24 16:59:00.000', 101),
        (timestamp '2021-10-24 16:57:00.000', 101),
        (timestamp '2021-10-24 16:55:00.000', 99)
)
SELECT date as Timestamp,
    val as NumericField
FROM (
        SELECT array_except(
                sequence(prev_ts, Timestamp, interval '1' minute),
                array [ prev_ts, timestamp ] -- exclude border values
            ) as dates,
            case
                NumericField
                when prev_num then prev_num
            end as val
        FROM (
                SELECT *,
                    lag(Timestamp) over(order by Timestamp) prev_ts,
                    lag(NumericField) over(order by Timestamp) prev_num
                FROM dataset
            )
    ) seq
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(dates) AS t (date)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM dataset
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Output:

| Timestamp | NumericField |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-24 16:55:00.000 | 99 |
| 2021-10-24 16:56:00.000 |  |
| 2021-10-24 16:57:00.000 | 101 |
| 2021-10-24 16:58:00.000 | 101 |
| 2021-10-24 16:59:00.000 | 101 |

Comment: Only question I have is how does only using LAG work when looking forward to the next record? I assumed using a mix of LEAD() and LAG() would have been the appropriate approach @Guru Stron

Comment: @user7298979 you don't need mix of both cause `lag`/`lead` are used against existing data (i.e. "previous" and "next" value will not change for the whole gap), so you take one of the functions (either `lag` or `lead`) for your calculation and comape the result with current value which is "next" (or "previous" for `lead`) for the gap.

Comment: So for the second example in my question, it would still return a null value then?

Comment: @user7298979 yes, value for `2021-10-24 16:56:00.000` timestamp represents exactly that.