# How to build date change query using presto sql

Tags: sql, presto

I need to make a tracker containing item name and price date change.
The date shows when the price is changed. I used lead, but it shows each day not when the day has changed.

for instance,
item name = A

- price date = 2022-11-21, price = $4
- price date = 2022-11-25, price = $3
- price date = 2022-11-30, price = $4

The expectation for the result is:

```
start date, next date, price
2022-11-21  2022-11-24  $4
2022-11-25  2022-11-29  $3
2022-11-30  2023-02-14 (current date)  $4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

#*Updated*:

The dataset is containing daily price
for instance :
item name = A

- price date = 2022-11-21, price = $4
- price date = 2022-11-22, price = $4
- price date = 2022-11-23, price = $4
- price date = 2022-11-24, price = $4
- price date = 2022-11-25, price = $3
- price date = 2022-11-26, price = $3
- price date = 2022-11-27, price = $3
- price date = 2022-11-29, price = $3
- price date = 2022-12-01, price = $4

Query :

```
select 
    item_name,
    supplier_name,
    price_date,
    price,
    lead(price_date) over (partition by item_name order by price) as next_price from
     price
```

Result:

- price = $4, 2022-11-21, 2022-11-22
- price = $4, 2022-11-22, 2022-11-23
- price = $4, 2022-11-23, 2022-11-24
- price = $3, 2022-11-25, 2022-11-26
- price = $3, 2022-11-26, 2022-11-27
- price = $3, 2022-11-27, 2022-11-29
- price = $3, 2022-11-29, 2022-11-30
- price = $4, 2022-12-01, 2023-02-14

While my expectation is :

- price = $4, 2022-11-21, 2022-11-25
- price = $3, 2022-11-26, 2022-11-30
- price = $4, 2023-12-01, 2023-02-14

Comment: I'd start with joining a calendar table.

Comment: Why not use a LEAD window function an subtract 1 day to get next date

Comment: TBH I don't fully understand the logic how the sample data transforms into the result. Why `$3` has disappeared?

Comment: @GuruStron My mistake, I fixed the expectation result

Comment: @nbk, I used lead, but somehow the date change will trace all date with same price.

Comment: then please show us your query you have with the output you get

Comment: @Stein please add the current query. And actual data cause it would be hard to get "every day" with `lead` with current one.

Comment: @nbk please find the update. thank you

Comment: @GuruStron please find the update. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try using gaps-and-island approach - i.e. introduce a column representing the change in price, use cumulative sum to calculate groups and use group by to calculate the results:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(date, price) as (
    values (date '2022-11-21', 4),
    (date '2022-11-22', 4),
    (date '2022-11-23', 4),
    (date '2022-11-24', 4),
    (date '2022-11-25', 3),
    (date '2022-11-26', 3),
    (date '2022-11-27', 3),
    (date '2022-11-29', 3),
    (date '2022-12-01', 4)
)

-- query
select arbitrary(price) price,
       min(date) as start_dt,
       max(date) as end_dt
from (
     select date, price, sum (change) over (order by date) as grp
     from (
        select *, if(lag(price) over (order by date) != price, 1, 0) as change
        from dataset)
     )
group by grp;
```

Output:

| price | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-11-24 |
| 3 | 2022-11-25 | 2022-11-29 |
| 4 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-01 |

Few notes:

1. since your actual data is partitioned - do not forget to add `item_name` for window partitioning and final group by
2. if you really need current date as the `end_dt` for final row in partition there are several ways to achieve that - not very fun with inserting missing dates (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744370/2501279) for inspiration) or you can just roll up another subquery which will check if `lead(end_dt) over (partition ... order by end_dt)` is null and use current date for `end_dt`